# Azure data factory ci/cd release errors

Tags: cicd, azure-data-factory

I am trying to deploy to the UAT environment and followed the needed steps shown in a blog post and youtube video.

However, I keep getting failures.

If I run it in 'validation only' mode it passes fine. But to actually deploy it under 'incremental' I receive the following errors

```
2022-03-01T17:24:27.6268601Z ##[error]At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.
2022-03-01T17:24:27.6301466Z ##[error]Details:
2022-03-01T17:24:27.6306699Z ##[error]BadRequest: Failed to encrypt sub-resource payload {
  "Id": "/subscriptions/a834838a-11d5-4657-a9c3-bc8b2ebdaa59/resourceGroups/adf-rg-uat-uks/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/adf-df-uat-uks/linkedservices/adfSQLDB_Dev",
  "Name": "adfSQLDB_Dev",
  "Properties": {
    "annotations": [],
    "type": "AzureSqlDatabase",
    "typeProperties": {
      "connectionString": "********************"
    }
  }
} and error is: Message for the errorCode not found..
2022-03-01T17:24:27.6314634Z ##[error]BadRequest: Failed to encrypt sub-resource payload {
  "Id": "/subscriptions/a834838a-11d5-4657-a9c3-bc8b2ebdaa59/resourceGroups/adf-rg-uat-uks/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/adf-df-uat-uks/linkedservices/adfSQLDB_Prod",
  "Name": "adfSQLDB_Prod",
  "Properties": {
    "annotations": [],
    "type": "AzureSqlDatabase",
    "typeProperties": {
      "connectionString": "********************"
    }
  }
} and error is: Message for the errorCode not found..
2022-03-01T17:24:27.6322501Z ##[error]BadRequest: Failed to encrypt sub-resource payload {
  "Id": "/subscriptions/a834838a-11d5-4657-a9c3-bc8b2ebdaa59/resourceGroups/adf-rg-uat-uks/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/adf-df-uat-uks/linkedservices/adfBlobStorage",
  "Name": "adfBlobStorage",
  "Properties": {
    "annotations": [],
    "type": "AzureBlobStorage",
    "typeProperties": {
      "connectionString": "********************"
    }
  }
} and error is: Expecting connection string of format "key1=value1; key2=value2"..
2022-03-01T17:24:27.6328134Z ##[error]BadRequest: Failed to encrypt sub-resource payload {
  "Id": "/subscriptions/a834838a-11d5-4657-a9c3-bc8b2ebdaa59/resourceGroups/adf-rg-uat-uks/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/adf-df-uat-uks/linkedservices/adfSQLDB",
  "Name": "adfSQLDB",
  "Properties": {
    "annotations": [],
    "type": "AzureSqlDatabase",
    "typeProperties": {
      "connectionString": "********************"
    }
  }
} and error is: Message for the errorCode not found..
2022-03-01T17:24:27.6336169Z ##[error]BadRequest: Failed to encrypt sub-resource payload {
  "Id": "/subscriptions/a834838a-11d5-4657-a9c3-bc8b2ebdaa59/resourceGroups/adf-rg-uat-uks/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/adf-df-uat-uks/linkedservices/adfSQLDB_UAT",
  "Name": "adfSQLDB_UAT",
  "Properties": {
    "annotations": [],
    "type": "AzureSqlDatabase",
    "typeProperties": {
      "connectionString": "********************"
    }
  }
} and error is: Message for the errorCode not found..
2022-03-01T17:24:27.6339122Z ##[error]Check out the troubleshooting guide to see if your issue is addressed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-resource-group-deployment?view=azure-devops#troubleshooting
2022-03-01T17:24:27.6342204Z ##[error]Task failed while creating or updating the template deployment.
```

Regards
Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking I found the issue was that the values were not being passed as secure string. I had the change the pipeline variables so they were secured and it went through ok

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any Self Hosted Integration Runtime? If yes, then please check it is in available state during the deployment or your connection string may not have the Secure String property:

```
"typeProperties": {
    "connectionString": {
        "type": "SecureString",
        "value": .............
  }
}
```

Comment: After checking I found the issue was that the values were not being passed as secure string. I had the change the pipeline variables so they were secured and it went through ok

Comment: Good to hear, request you to mark the response as an answer so that others from community can get benefit from it. Thanks :)